# can't seem to retrieve data from this api in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, api, jsx

```
import react from 'react';    
export default class App extends react.Component {
  state = {
    loading: true,
    person: null,
  }
```

> having difficulty in getting the data to be rendered. data does show on console log but won't display names on react page
> please help.

**any help would be appreciated thank you**

Comment: `const url = <https://api.jsonbin.io/b/5e9ef690435f5604bb4567dd>;` is invalid syntax

Comment: Remove the < > in the url you need to use a string 'https://api.jsonbin.io/b/5e9ef690435f5604bb4567dd' or "https://api.jsonbin.io/b/5e9ef690435f5604bb4567dd"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the API response:

```
[{"id":1,"title":"Mr","firstName":"Danny","lastName":"Dyer","dob":"24/07/1977","active":true},{"id":2,"title":"Mr","firstName":"Nicholas","lastName":"Cage","dob":"07/01/1964","active":true},{"id":3,"title":"Miss","firstName":"Emma","lastName":"Watson","dob":"15/04/1990","active":true},{"id":4,"title":"Prof","firstName":"Bryan","lastName":"Cox","dob":"03/03/1968","active":true}]
```

It's an array of objects. `data.res[0]` would make sense only if the API response was an *object* containing a `res` property, eg

```
{
  "res": [
    {"id":1, ...
```

So, change your code from

```
person: data.res[0]
```

to

```
person: data[0]
```

and from

```
<div>{this.state.person.name.title}</div>
<div>{this.state.person.name.first}</div>
<div>{this.state.person.name.last}</div>
```

to

```
<div>{this.state.person.title}</div>
<div>{this.state.person.firstName}</div>
<div>{this.state.person.lastName}</div>
```

to properly navigate the data.

(also make sure to enclose the `url` in string delimiters `'` or `"`, not `<` `>`)

Live snippet:

```js
class App extends React.Component {
  state = {
    loading: true,
    person: null,
  }
  componentDidMount() {
    const url = 'https://api.jsonbin.io/b/5e9ef690435f5604bb4567dd';
    fetch(url)
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then(data => this.setState({ person: data[0], loading: false }));
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        {this.state.loading || !this.state.person ? (
          <div>loading...</div>
        ) : (
            <div>
              <div>{this.state.person.title}</div>
              <div>{this.state.person.firstName}</div>
              <div>{this.state.person.lastName}</div>
            </div>
          )}
      </div>
    );
  }
}
ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.querySelector('.react'));
```

```html
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@16/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
<div class="react"></div>
```

Comment: once this is done what would be the best way to display the data?

Comment: did that but it seems to only show on the console, not the actual page itself.

Comment: It works just fine here, see runnable snippet. If it doesn't for you, make sure to save the changes to the JS and re-compile the app

Answer (score 0):

I actually did it a different way by using ! {this.state.loading || !this.state.person ? (